# Source for fancy_echo usage and documentation

Tags: bash, shell

I was looking starting point for an install script that will allow me to automatically provision a new or re-imaged computer and came across [one by thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop/blob/master/mac). However, it makes frequent use of a command that I'm not familiar with, fancy_echo.

```
fancy_echo() {
  local fmt="$1"; shift # shellcheck disable=SC2059
  printf "\n$fmt\n" "$@"
}
```

It's also used in this [script by dockyard](https://github.com/DockYard/laptop-install/blob/master/install.sh):

```
fancy_echo "This script will setup your laptop"
fancy_echo "If you want to reuse your old SSH key, copy your SSH config over before running this script"
fancy_echo "During installation, it will ask for your sudo password a few times"
```

Since this is run in the command line and looks like bash, I've tried the man pages, the [standalone GNU info system](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html) and the --help option, all with no luck. I presume it prints to the screen but I don't know, so I'm asking. Here are my questions:

1. What is fancy_echo and how does it differ from echo?
2. What is a good source of documentation on it?

Comment: It's not a command, it's just that custom function that it defined for itself. It's just like `printf`, except it automatically puts a newline before and after the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a standard command, there's no documentation, it's just the function whose definition you copied, which is internal to that package.

```
fancy_echo format_string arg arg arg....
```

is equivalent to

```
printf format_string arg arg arg....
```

except that it adds newlines around the output.